# Unity 2d error' Transform' does not contain a definition for 'postion'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, position

I want to create a 2d game but when I want the player to avoid being able to jump infinitely in the air by recovering his position I get an error.

My error :

> Transform' does not contain a definition for 'postion' and no
> accessible extension method 'postion' accepting a first argument of
> type 'Transform' could be found

My code :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float moveSpeed;
    public float jumpForce;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;
    public bool isJumping;
    public bool isGrounded;

    public Transform groundCheckLeft;
    public Transform groundCheckRight;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapArea(groundCheckLeft.Position, groundCheckRight.Position);

        float horizontalMovement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
        {
            isJumping = true;
        }

        MovePlayer(horizontalMovement);
    }

    void MovePlayer(float _horizontalMovement)
    {
        Vector3 targetVelocity = new Vector2(_horizontalMovement, rb.velocity.y);
        rb.velocity = Vector3.SmoothDamp(rb.velocity, targetVelocity, ref velocity, .05F);

        if(isJumping == true)
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jumpForce));
            isJumping = false;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's transform.pos**i**tion not postion

Edit: Yep, just like Snir Ego said.

Answer (score 0):

the solution should be simple, you wrote `groundCheckLeft.Postion` instead of `groundCheckLeft.position`